# Zookeeper and Kafka with SASL security

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, sasl

I've setup a Kafka cluster with [SASL SCRAM](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-84%3A+Support+SASL+SCRAM+mechanisms) security, and it's working fine.

Per the documentation, I have used the command `kafka-configs.sh` to create a username and password and grant that user access to a topic.

That also works great.

However, the `kafka-configs.sh` command doesn't require any kind of authentication itself, so it occurs to me that ANYONE could run that command and create their own user in Kafka and grant their own permissions.

Perhaps I need to enable SASL security on Zookeeper? But I can't find any consistent or working documentation on how to do that. Adding properties to `zookeeper.config` like `requireclientauthscheme=sasl` doesn't seem to do anything.  Or at least it doesn't stop `kafka-configs.sh` from creating new users in zookeeper without any sort of authentication.

Am I even going down a viable path here?  Or do I need to back up and do something different?

For reference, I'm using Kafka 1.0.0 and Zookeper 3.4.11.  But I'm flexible on versions if some other version works better.

Any help appreciated!  :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've finally hacked through a solution for this. :)

Basically, you need to use Zookeeper's on `setAcl` command to lock down the node `/config/users`. The documentation of how to use SASL to authenticate a Zookeeper ACL is poor at best. The normal Zookeeper mechanism of using `addauth` to authenticate doesn't work with SASL, because SASL has to happen at startup, not later as Zookeeper expects.

The syntax for `setAcl` is tricky, and if you get it wrong you can lock yourself out forever. So be careful. But Zookeeper does have a way to inject a super-user at startup to get yourself out of situations like that.

So for your `kafka-configs.sh`, you have to specify the `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=[some file]` parameter to pass in your client credentials to Zookeeper. And the server credentials are likewise in the JAAS file on the Zookeeper server.

I can provide additional technical details on my solution if anyone needs them, but somehow I suspect I'm one of the few people trying to seriously secure Kafka and Zookeeper using SASL_SCRAM.  :)

I do hope SASL_SCRAM catches on though, because Kerberos is a three-headed beast of a technology that I'd rather not use unless I have to.  :P

Comment: Hi Beaker , Can you explain in detail the process you used to secure kafka-zookeeper with SASL_SCRAM . I would also like to know if this scheme prevents man-in-middle attacks or would I have to enable SSL in addition.

Comment: For Kafka, I'm using SASL_SCRAM over SSL for everything.

However, Zookeeper doesn't support SASL_SCRAM.  Zookeeper doesn't even support SSL!  The "kafka-acls" command will store Kafka's ACL's in Zookeeper.

So you need to set an ACL to protect /config/users in Zookeeper. 
 Authentication as user "super" requires enabling DigestLoginModule security for Zookeeper.

Lack of SSL is still a problem, but someone would have to be sniffing traffic when you issue kafka-acls commands, 

It's not perfect security, but it will discourage the casual data voyuer from getting access. :)

Comment: My current strategy is to secure the zookeeper cluster access to within our VPC and enable SSL for interbroker communication in kafka cluster. Is there a documentation that you followed to setup SASL_SCRAM for kafka.? . Please provide the configuration steps used .

Comment: Yes, I found this page most helpful:  https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl_scram.html

It's documentation for Confluent, but this part applies 100% to plain Kafka too